# AngularJS - how to write a unit test for an asyncronous funtion with karma & jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing an app with AngularJS 1.5. I have some code in my service that I want to test. My service has a promise in it. I tried to write a unit test for it but it doesn't work. I am using Karma and Jasmine.

https://codepen.io/aubz/pen/VoWgbR

Here is my code snippet:

```
self.verifyCode = function(pin) {
  var savedPin = localStorage.getItem("PIN");

  if (savedPin == null) {
    return $q.reject("NO_PIN_SET");
  }

  if (pin !== savedHashedPin) {
    return $q.reject("INCORRECT_PIN");
  }

  return $q.when(true);
};

xit('should throw an error because there is no stored pin code', function () {

    var pin = '1234';

    Service
        .verifyCode(pin)
        .then(function (result) {
            expect(result).toBe(null);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            expect(error).not.toBe(null);
            expect(error).toBe('NO_PIN_SET');
        });

});
```

Comment: See e.g. https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: If the service returns a rejected promise, the `.then` block should be skipped, not expect the result to be `null`.

Comment: @johrsharpe can you explain or give an example because I don't understand the documentation